# Module not found: Can't resolve 'history' in '/Users/aronfischer/the_odin_project/passport-starter/src'

Tags: reactjs, npm, error-handling

I'm getting this error: 
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'history' in '/Users/aronfischer/the_odin_project/passport-starter/src'` when running `npm start` and I can't figure out why. 
The file tree should be fine or am I missing something.

My history.js modules just includes the following code:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"
export default createBrowserHistory()
```

I already tried deleted the package.lock.json and the node_modules files and ran npm start again, but didn't change the error.
This is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXAbZ.png) of my application, it also includes the file tree for reference.

Thanks already

Comment: Do you have a dependency to `history`? Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes I ran npm install. And what do you mean if I have a dependancy to history?

Comment: Do you have the `history` package in your `package.json`? If not you can add it by running `npm --save history`.

Comment: ok let me try this really quick

Comment: yes great it worked with ```npm i --save history```But now I'm getting the same module not found error with the App.jsx file. Is there a dependance I have to install to being able to use the .jsx extension

Comment: Not a dependency per se, but you might have to _transpile_ your code for it to be able to run. That's another problem that we won't solve in the comment section though. I'll post the answer as a solution and you'll have to post another question for that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `history` dependency installed to use it.

```sh
npm install --save history
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a module not found, can't resolve error for my App.jsx file. Is there also a dependency I have to install to being able to use .jsx file extensions?

Comment: If it worked you should "Mark it as the solution" by clicking the check mark.